# Insert input data from HTML form into JSON object and then store it in MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, json

I am trying to get the data from user registration form in HTML and then push the data to JSON and then get the JSON and store into MySQL. Please help me.

**HTML**

```
    <form id="myForm" action="userInfo.php" method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="FirstNameLabel" class="tableproperties">First Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="signupTextBoxStyle" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" id="FirstNameBox" required/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="LastNameLabel" class="tableproperties">Last Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" id="LastNameBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="eMailLabel" class="tableproperties">Email</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" id="eMailBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
            <td id="emailStatus"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="passwordLabel" class="tableproperties">Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="passwordTextbox" maxlength="24" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-info-circle infoIcon" title="Password must contain minimum 3 upper case, 2 lower case and 2 special chars"></i></td>
            <td><progress value="0" max="100" class="progressBar" id="progressStatus"></progress></td>
            <td id="passwordStrength"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="confirmPasswordLabel" class="tableproperties">Confirm Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Must be same as password" maxlength="24" id="confirmPasswordBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
            <td id="passwordMismatch"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="dobLabel" class="tableproperties">D.O.B</label></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="dob" placeholder="Enter D.O.B" id="dobBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="dobTimeLabel" class="tableproperties">D.O.B with time</label></td>
            <td><input type="datetime" name="dobTime" placeholder="Enter D.O.B with time" id="dobTimeBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="localDOBLabel" class="tableproperties">Local D.O.B</label></td>
            <td><input type="datetime-local" name="localdob" placeholder="Enter Local D.O.B" id="localDobBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="ssnLabel" class="tableproperties">SSN</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ssn" placeholder="000-00-0000" id="ssnBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required pattern="^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="usPhoneNumber" class="tableproperties" >US Phone Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="000-000-0000" id="usNumberBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required></td>
            <td id="phoneStatus"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="creditLabel" class="tableproperties" id="CreditText">Credit Card Number</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="creditCardNumber" placeholder="Enter Credit Card Number" id="creditBox" class="signupTextBoxStyle" required pattern="^[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{4})?$"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block signupbuttonStyle" id="sub" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block signupbuttonStyle" onclick="location.href = 'index.html';">Cancel</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**PHP**(Just to test  Data is getting saved to mySQL if i manually enter the data)

```
$json_obj = '{
      "jsonFirstName": "Kishan",
      "jsonLastName": "Kishan",
      "jsonEmail": "Kishan",
      "jsonPassword": "Kishan",
      "jsonDob": "Kishan",
      "jsonDobTime": "Kishan",
      "jsonLocaldob": "Kishan",
      "jsonSsn": "Kishan",
      "jsonPhonenumber": "Kishan",
      "jsonCreditcardnumber": "Kishan"
 }';
```

**PHP**(Error if i want to get the values from the form)

```
$json_obj = '{
      "jsonFirstName": (string) $_POST['firstName'],
      "jsonLastName": (string) $_POST['lastName'],
      "jsonEmail": (string) $_POST['email'],
      "jsonPassword": (string) $_POST['password'],
      "jsonDob": (string) $_POST['dob'],
      "jsonDobTime": (string) $_POST['dobTime'],
      "jsonLocaldob": (string) $_POST['localdob'],
      "jsonSsn": (string) $_POST['ssn'],
      "jsonPhonenumber": (string) $_POST['phone'],
      "jsonCreditcardnumber": (string) $_POST['creditCardNumber']
 }';
```

**Error Description** 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'firstName' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/297test/userInfo.php on line 19

**REST of PHP Code**
$result = json_decode($json_obj);

```
$firstname = $result->jsonFirstName;
$lastname = $result->jsonLastName;
$email = $result->jsonEmail;
$password = $result->jsonPassword;
$dob = $result->jsonDob;
$dobTime = $result->jsonDobTime;
$localdob = $result->jsonLocaldob;
$ssn = $result->jsonSsn;
$phonenumber = $result->jsonPhonenumber;
$creditcardnumber = $result->jsonCreditcardnumber;


if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password', '$dob', '$dobTime', '$localdob', '$ssn','$phonenumber','$creditcardnumber')")){
    echo "Successfully Inserted";
}

else
    echo "Fail to Insert";
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it in json?

Comment: i don't understand why do you need to make the POST variables into a json string, then decoding it, then using it again. it doesnt make sense

Comment: $json_obj = "{'jsonFirstName': " . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName'] . ")} - Or better, use prepared statements...

Comment: i am just working on an assignment in my university.. these are the requirements...i need to get the form input in json and then parse it to SQL server...

Comment: @Fabian it stil doent wrk..thanks fr your inputs :(

Comment: you have to wrap the whole string with a call to json_encode(....) so you get an actual json object and not a string.

Comment: @Fabian     $result = json_decode('{
          "jsonFirstName": (string) $_POST['firstName'],
          "jsonLastName": (string) $_POST['lastName'],
          "jsonEmail": (string) $_POST['email'],
          "jsonPassword": (string) $_POST['password'],
          "jsonDob": (string) $_POST['dob'],
          "jsonDobTime": (string) $_POST['dobTime'],
          "jsonLocaldob": (string) $_POST['localdob'],
          "jsonSsn": (string) $_POST['ssn'],
          "jsonPhonenumber": (string) $_POST['phone'],
          "jsonCreditcardnumber": (string) $_POST['creditCardNumber']
     }');

Comment: @fabian..with the changes you told me getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'firstName' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/297test/userInfo.php on line 33"  I am really sry..i am totally new to this..so facing many new problems at the same time ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating JSON-Strings directly through concatenation is hard because of quotes, new line characters etc.

Instead, create an array of values and encode that into a JSON string with `json_encode`:

```
$values = array(
  "jsonFirstName" =>        $_POST['firstName'],
  "jsonLastName" =>         $_POST['lastName'],
  "jsonEmail" =>            $_POST['email'],
  "jsonPassword" =>         $_POST['password'],
  "jsonDob" =>              $_POST['dob'],
  "jsonDobTime" =>          $_POST['dobTime'],
  "jsonLocaldob" =>         $_POST['localdob'],
  "jsonSsn" =>              $_POST['ssn'],
  "jsonPhonenumber" =>      $_POST['phone'],
  "jsonCreditcardnumber" => $_POST['creditCardNumber']
);

$json_obj = json_encode($values);
```

Alternatively you can just do:

```
$json_obj = json_encode($_POST);
```

You will then get a JSON object with every index of `$_POST`. The only difference is, that you can't rename your fields as you did in your example.

Comment: thanks...so far its gng on gud....when i echo $json_obj..i get the following result( {"jsonFirstName":"userfirst","jsonLastName":"userlast","jsonEmail":"user@gmail.com","jsonPassword":"QWERqwer!@#$","jsonDob":"2014-01-01","jsonDobTime":"dobtime","jsonLocaldob":"2014-01-01T01:00","jsonSsn":"123-12-1234","jsonPhonenumber":"123-123-1234","jsonCreditcardnumber":"123412341234"})...can you pls guide me how to store these values each one by one in the mySQl server...that would solve my issue actually..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing it this way, however the parse error is because you are using a single quote to open the string and then also using that to pick the array index.

Change `$_POST['firstName']` to use double quotes such as `$_POST["firstName"]`

Comment: it stil doesnt wrk..this error comes in Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/297test/userInfo.php on line 35 "$firstname = $result->jsonFirstName;"-->this line it is pointing out

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
Try to do this.

```
$array = (
      "jsonFirstName" =>  $_POST['firstName'],
      "jsonLastName" =>  $_POST['lastName'],
      "jsonEmail" => $_POST['email'],
      "jsonPassword" => $_POST['password'],
      "jsonDob" => $_POST['dob'],
      "jsonDobTime" => $_POST['dobTime'],
      "jsonLocaldob" => $_POST['localdob'],
      "jsonSsn" => $_POST['ssn'],
      "jsonPhonenumber" => $_POST['phone'],
      "jsonCreditcardnumber" => $_POST['creditCardNumber']
 );

$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: still no luck..the error now is "parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/297test/userInfo.php on line 18"

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/297test/userInfo.php ..i am getting this new error :(

Comment: You forgot to start with `$array=array([...]);`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because you are creating the `JSON` object out of the `POST` variables in a wrong way. There is indeed an issue with quotes in your statement. It should rather be something like:

```
  $json_obj = '{
  "jsonFirstName": "'.(string) $_POST['firstName'].'",
  "jsonLastName": "'.(string) $_POST['lastName'].'",
  "jsonEmail": "'.(string) $_POST['email'].'",
  "jsonPassword": "'.(string) $_POST['password'].'",
  "jsonDob": "'.(string) $_POST['dob'].'",
  "jsonDobTime": "'.(string) $_POST['dobTime'].'",
  "jsonLocaldob": "'.(string) $_POST['localdob'].'",
  "jsonSsn": "'.(string) $_POST['ssn'].'",
  "jsonPhonenumber": "'.(string) $_POST['phone'].'",
  "jsonCreditcardnumber": "'.(string) $_POST['creditCardNumber'].'"
  }';
```

If I just include the variable without the double quotes while constructing the `JSON` object I get something like:

```
  $name = "Foo";
  $json_obj = '{"firstName" :'.$name.'}'; 

 //gets expanded to $json_obj = {"firstname" : Foo}
 //Whereas it should be $json_obj = {"firstname" :"Foo"}
```

It was because of the missing double quotes, you could not create a `JSON` object in the first place and therefore when you tried to decode it and further access an attribute, it gave an error suggesting :

```
 Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/297test/userInfo.php on line 35
```

Try the code snippet I gave, it should hopefully help you out.