# How do you dump data from a html form into .json using PHP(or any other back-end language)?

Tags: html, json, forms

So, i'm developing a form that will be checked by a program to be executed with the data.  How do you dump the data into a .json file with html forms or any other language?

For sake of the project i'll give a section of the html form to help understand.

```
<form action="/folder/data.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="submit">Sumbit!</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my (limited) experience, "action" in the  links to a PHP file to process the submitted form fields, like so: [Insert input data from HTML form into JSON object and then store it in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229547/insert-input-data-from-html-form-into-json-object-and-then-store-it-in-mysql)).

Basically, you'll be converting your input fields into a JSON object with '[json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)' (for PHP) or something similar.

You may want to check out this question: [How to send a JSON object using html form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195065/how-to-send-a-json-object-using-html-form-data)